# How to detect if an rspec file is being run as part of a test suite

Tags: rspec

From inside the spec file how do I detect if the file is being run as part of a test suite or by itself.  If it is being run by itself, I want verbose output, but if it is being as one file of many, then I want to suppress the output.

For example if the file is 'spec/models/my_model_spec.rb' I want to tell the difference between

```
rspec spec
```

and

```
rspec spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this commented out in my `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
# Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
# file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
# individual spec file.
if config.files_to_run.one?
  # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
  # unless a formatter has already been configured
  # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
  config.default_formatter = "doc"
end
```

Moving it into the `RSpec.configure do |config|` block produced the results you're looking for.

**EDIT**

RSpec supplies four different output formatters: progress, documentation, HTML, and JSON. The last two are self explanatory. The first one, progress, is the default formatter. It prints dots representing the progress within the test run. Green dots equal a successful test run.

The other formatter, documentation, uses the `describe`, `context`, and `it` descriptions to show test results. So, given this RSpec structure:

```
describe Stack do
  describe '#push' do
    context 'when the stack is empty' do
      it 'increases the size of the stack by 1'
    end
    context 'when the stack is full' do
      it 'throws a stack overflow exception'
      it 'does not increase the size of the stack'
    end
  end
end
```

The Documentation formatter would output this:

```
Stack
  #push
    when the stack is empty
      increases the size of the stack by 1
    when the stack is full
      throws a stack overflow exception
      does not increase the size of the stack
```

You can try out the various formatters on the command line, like this:

```
rspec --format progress
rspec --format doc (or documentation)
rspec --format html
rspec --format json
```

The configuration code in the spec_helper above allows you to change the default_formatter for situations where you are only running one file. You can always override the default formatter by specifying a different one on the command line.

The comments on the RSpec source code helped me answer this question: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/7b6b9c3f2e2878213f97d6fc9e9eb23c323cfe1c/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb